# RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int) throws null point exception in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

When I am trying to hide `RelativeLayout` in my `Fragment` I get an `Exception` that `RelativeLayout.setVisibility` throws null point `Exception`.
Here is my `Fragment` code:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_description_zoom_image,container,false);
    layout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_fix);
    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return view;
}
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/layout_fix">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/btnFavourite"
        android:text="@string/add_to_favourite"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"/>
```

Comment: Code of product_description_zoom_image.xml? Does it same what you added in question?

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct layout for fragment

Comment: Maybe your reference of layout is not right please check it again.

Comment: move  layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);    this line to onviewcreated method

Comment: @SandeepParish `super.onCreateView()` is optional.

Comment: Post full `product_description_zoom_image.xml`

Comment: Lot of guessing in the answers. The only reason why your `RelativeLayout` with the id `layout_fix` is `null` is if it's not available the layout file of your Fragment.

On a side-note, if you'd use `DataBinding` you wouldn't get this issue, as you can't access items that are not available in the layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Add your error log will help others to find what was the exact issue?

Comment: and also ho i can hide toolbar in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like Android Studio cannot handle too many nested layouts. So please  remove the parent RelativeLayout,and create a new Relative as child of parent layout and put everything in the new Relative layout. That solved it.

or

`product_description_zoom_image`
 layout has not any layout with id `layout_fix`

and your question in comment

```
Put this code in fragment in which you want to hide toolbar...

 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

Comment: How is this different from OP's code? The only difference is that you've removed some annotations that is only used by Lint, hence it's not used in any way on runtime.

Comment: check your layout file is contains same layout with id `layout_fix`

Comment: What are you talking about? Your answer is wrong and the single line of description you added should've been a comment to OP's question, not an answer as you're basically just guessing that this might be the issue.

Comment: Check i updated my answer and it will fix your issue @Darwind

Comment: It's not my issue, I'm just commenting on the question and answers.

Comment: yes. solved it. and also how can i hide toolbar in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
RelativeLayout layout;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);
    initView(view);
    return view;

}

private void initView(View view) {
    layout=view.findViewById(R.id.layout_fix);
    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

xml code like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout_fix">

<Button
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Hellow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```